# energy efficiency, transformation from chemical to thermal energy, for district heating plants

Tags: energy, heat

If I have a system in which I introduce 100e.u.F  (energy units) derived from chemical energy (i.e. fuel) and generate thermal energy to heat water what are e.u. absorbed by water? I.e. the efficiency of the transformation?

Basically I would like to know the average/general efficiency of energy transformation for a district heating plant. Considered that the only energy input is fuel and the only energy output is heat (no electricity)?

What are the energy loss?

Thanks, Luther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.labplan.ufsc.br/congressos/wseas/papers/517-455.pdf (see references there): "In general, today average values for heat generator efficiencies are about 0.8-0.85 for residential equipment (< 50 kWt) and 0.9 for bigger (industrial) boilers." You should also take into account heat losses in distribution (in pipelines etc.), not just in boilers.